# Can anyone help identify this, possibly Greek, type of uniform/dress?

Tags: identification, uniform

I found this old picture of my great great grandfather and my mother isn’t sure what he is wearing. She did say we have some Greek roots from one side of the family. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Do you have any other information? The more you can tell us, the more likely it is that someone can help you. For example, do you know when your great great grandfather was born, or how old he was in this photo? Are there any clues on the back of the photo as to when or where it was taken?

Comment: Also, what *fraternal organizations* might your grandfather been a member of? My initial reaction, given the unusual plinth just to your grandfather's right, is that this might be fraternal regalia of some sort.

Comment: I initially thought it might be Ottoman Empire, but the crown & crossed hammers/picks on the belt buckle would most likely negate that. Was your great great grandfather involved with mining or tunneling?

Answer (score 1):

Your great great grandfather is wearing the miners habit or berghabit in german which is used because he is a member of a mining association. The photo dates from before ww1. The uniform could depend on different associations. They are still worn today.
[image][image][image]

Comment: OK. 2nd pic pretty spot hitting.  Could you include the insignia, 'left claw' - a shield… and further describe verbally what _you_ see visually…: buttons do not match as do not feathers…

Comment: As I've said before the uniform could be different with each mining association.